# Finding the numbers that make up the diagonal line in Pascal's Triangle

Tags: java, algorithm, pascals-triangle

In Java, I am trying to figure out how to get the numbers that make up the diagonal lines in Pascal's triangle:
[image]
[Credit: Britannica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOQ5a.png)

For example, if I wanted to get the 6th diagonal line of pascal's triangle (which is the Fibonacci number 8), I would get the values (1,4,3).

My original plan was to use a loop to find the middle values of the triangle(since the first value is always 1 and the last value alternates between 1 and another number) for each diagonal, but I am not too sure how exactly to implement it. I am still trying to think of a better method to find the values for each diagonal, but this is all I could think of so far.

If someone could guide me, that would be very helpful!

Sorry if this post was unclear or misunderstanding, I am not too good at English.

Comment: Your English is flawless.

Answer (score 3):

Let *n* be the number of diagonal, with the first diagonal numbered 0. Let *j* go from 0 to *n / 2* (the integer quotient). Then the numbers on the diagonal are the binomial coefficients *(n-j)* C *j*.

For your example, *n* is 5 (not 6). This gives *j* going from 0 to 2, and the binomial coefficients 5C0, 4C1, 3C2. Those are 1, 4, 3.

You can compute the binomial coefficients using the usual formula with factorials, or you can construct them on demand recursively using the sum formula for Pascal's triangle, memoizing already computed values.

Answer (score 1):

You could incrementally keep information about the last two diagonals. For instance, you could combine the last two diagonals in one array in zig-zag manner.

Let's say you have that zig-zag for the diagonals that sum up to 5 and 8 respectively -- depicted by the orange lines in the image below -- then you can easily derive the zig-zag for the diagonals that sum up to 8 and 13 -- depicted by the green lines in the image:

[image]

The base numbers are available for updating the values at every other index (skipping one, updating one).

So the starting point was this (orange) array:

```
   [1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1]
```

To get the next (green) array, we prefix with a new 0, and then perform pair-wise additions from left to right:

```
[0, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1]
 | /   | /   | /
 |/    |/    |/
[1, 1, 5, 4, 6, 3, 1]
```

When you need the result for a given diagonal, then you would allocate the space for this array and populate it with zeroes (instead of prepending a zero to a dynamic array/queue), and start with 1 at the right most array entry.

Then loop to apply the above logic to get to the zig-zag that includes the diagonal that you need. Finally extract the values of that diagonal, which are sitting at even indices in the zig-zag array.

Here is an implementation in a JavaScript snippet:

```js
function pascalDiagonal(n) {
    const arr = Array(n - 1).fill(0);
    arr.push(1); // right-most value is 1 (base case - top of triangle)
    
    for (let k = n - 1; k > 0; k--)
        for (let i = k; i < n; i += 2)
            arr[i-1] += arr[i]; // pair wise sums
    
    // Extract the result (at even indices)
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 2)
        result.push(arr[i]);
    return result;
}

console.log(pascalDiagonal(7));
```

Note that in this implementation the argument (`n`) is the 1-based number of the diagonal. So adjust with 1 if you need it to be zero-based.